# Converting Date to milli seconds in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimeinterval, nstimezone

hi am using following to convert date to string in objective C.

```
-(void)convertDateToJsonString:(NSString *)strDate
{


    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];


    NSDate * date =[formatter dateFromString:strDate];

    long long milliseconds = (long long)([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);

    NSLog(@"After conversion %lli",milliseconds);



}
```

its giving date but always getting time is **00:00:00** something not current time.How to get selected date with current time in milli second.

but its working for current date like below

```
 long long millisecs = (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);

    NSLog(@"After conversion %lli",millisecs);
```

Am getting from date picker date and converting.

And also for getting exact time zone like +530 in ios is there any methods?
i know **[NSTimezone Systemzone]** but its giving whole value like **"Asia/kolkatta +..."**

Comment: if the initial string date doesn't have any hours or minutes. How could `dateFromString` guess?

Comment: so i have to get time also from string then can get milli second right? @Larme

Comment: You don't show us how you display time, so anything we say would be a conjecture, other than to observe that if you only parse date and not time then you won't magically get time from somewhere.

Comment: "Am getting from date picker date and converting."  If you're getting the source date from a date picker, why don't you just leave it as an NSDate, vs converting to string and back?

Comment: To get the timezone in the format you desire simply use "Z" in the date format string of the date formatter you use to convert the NSDate to a string date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `strDate` is not getting parsed by `dateFromString:`.  The result is that your `date` will be `nil` and `timeInternvalSince1970` will do some default processing on `nil`.  You can confirm this by adding:

```
NSAssert (nil != date);
```

after your initialize `date`.  The assertion will fail.

The solution is that you need a better `formatter` - one that is consistent with the format of the passed in `strDate`.

But, perhaps you have a more fundamental problem.  The `UIDatePicker` `date` property returns an `NSDate` object directly.  Where are you getting your `strDate` from?

Comment: hi @GoZoner am getting date is correct only the problem is time always 00:00:00+5:30 am getting.Thanks for your reply friend

Comment: Okay.  Why are you using a `strDate` as an `NSString` instead of just getting an `NSDate` directly from your `NSDatePicker` using the `date` property?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added hours, minutes and seconds in NSDateFormatter like this

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];